# Getting Server sellection error: contect deadline exceded, current topology

Tags: mongodb, go

I am very new to Go Lang. I have started a project with MongoDB for implementing restful API but I am getting below error when running the main.go.

> PS C:\Users\dalvendra.kumar\Documents\GO_API_Mongo> go run main.go
> 2022/12/01 13:34:22 server selection error: context deadline exceeded, current topology: { Type: Unknown, Servers: [{ Addr: cluster0.n6dvjfs.mongodb.net:27017, Type: Unknown, Last error: connection() error occurred during connection handshake: dial tcp:
> lookup cluster0.n6dvjfs.mongodb.net: no such host }, ] }

```
package main

import (    
        "gin-mongo-api/configs"
        "gin-mongo-api/routes"
        "github.com/gin-gonic/gin" 
       )

func main() {   
     router := gin.Default()    
     configs.ConnectDB()
     routes.UserRoute(router)
     router.Run("localhost:6000")
   }
```

---

```
package routes

import (
        "gin-mongo-api/controllers"
        "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
       )

func UserRoute(router *gin.Engine) { 
    router.POST("/user", controllers.CreateUser())

    router.GET("/user/:userId", controllers.AddAuser())

    router.PUT("/user/:userId", controllers.EditUser())

    router.DELETE("/user/:userId", controllers.DeleteAUser())

    router.GET("/users", controllers.GetAllUsers()) 
    }
```

Comment: you have passed wrong mongodb uri, host `cluster0.n6dvjfs.mongodb.net` doesn't exists.

Comment: @bogdanoff I just copy that uri from https://cloud.mongodb.com/ just placed my password